# In Spring 3, can I instantiate an abstract class bean that will have abstract methods advised?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I want to do a sort of ORM framework for my needs. I want to describe my models as abstract classes, because they will have some methods implemented and some will be left abstract, annotated and should be implemented (actually, their execution intercepted) by aspect bean. Is it possible to implement this cleanly, without much config? Ideally, I would prefer no XML configuration on model beans.

**UPD:** The idea is that I don't want any explicit implementing or extending classes. AOP will create a proxy anyway - can it be automatically used as an instance of my bean?

**UPD2:** Almost two years have passed and I wanted to mark the first answer as the correct one.

So it seems that my idea was forecasting Spring Data JPA. They use custom namespace to create beans that automatically implement corresponding interfaces of JPA repositories. I believe a factory pattern is used for that.

Also, with Spring's JavaConfig you can easily instantiate and enhance your class instance before returning it as a bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is "yes", simply because it's possible to advise interfaces.  Interfaces are pure abstract methods, so it should be possible.

As for the amount of configuration, it'll take what it takes.  I don't know whether XML or annotations will work for you, but you'll only have to advise the interface or abstract class.  Classes that implement or extend get the advice without additional effort

Answer (score 0):

I always seem to run into this, and can never remember exactly what the deal is...but I believe it is that for advice, you must declare as an interface, that can be implemented by any sort of classes you wish, but the variable that will be proxied must be declared to the interface.